# C# dealing with objects

Tags: c#, php

so im using this library for C#, im a php developer, and when i get a list of users by using the following: http://help.globalscape.com/help/eft5_com/Retrieving_a_list_of_users.htm

I get an object, now in php i would just -> to break into this object and then foreach to loop through all the array elements to check if a user exists, but i am unsure how to do this in c#, can anyone help me out.

Comment: Can you show the code you already have of how you retrieve the users?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can make use of LINQ feature of C# do that thing easily.......

Something lijke

```
var students = new Student[]
        {
            new Student(82495, "Carlton", "Blanchard"),
            new Student(20935, "Charlotte", "O'Keefe"),
            new Student(79274, "Christine", "Burns"),
            new Student(79204, "Edward", "Swanson"),
            new Student(92804, "Charles", "Pressmann")
        };

        IEnumerable<Student> pupils = from studs
                                      in students  
                                      where stds.id = youridvaruabble/value
                                      select studs;
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to do more specifically? Just a foreach? What's in the object?

```
foreach(var item in UserArray) { 
    if (item.Name == "Something") { Response.Write("Here he is!"); }
}
```

Comment: Error: foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'object' because 'object' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

Comment: So i guess the objects contains an array? Don't you have a corresponding class for the object?